# Should DocumentDB OfferThroughput be set in Code?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

One of the most difficult things with DocumentDB is figuring out how many Request Units per Second (RUs/s) you need to run your application day to day but also during usage spikes. When you get this wrong, the DocumentDB client will throw exceptions, which is a terrible usage model.

I have seen the OfferThroughput value hard coded to 400 (which seems to be the lowest RUs/s) when creating a new collection in the DocumentDB samples. I would have thought that setting it in the Azure portal would be best, so it can be changed dynamically without having to do code changes.

What is the scenario for setting it in code and which value takes precedence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Azure Portal and the SDKs use the REST API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt632095.aspx) to update the throughput of a collection. The portal uses DocumentDB's JavaScript client-side SDK.  So there is no precedence or preferences order - the last call to update performance will be effective on the collection.

Regarding which scenarios set offer throughput in code vs. in the portal, this depends on your preference and deployment process. For production applications, code is better since you can automate easily. You can change throughput dynamically or do it uniformly from configuration for a number of collections.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree, the provisioning model for buying throughput on DocumentDB seems very un-cloud-y. In effect, you're either pre-provisioning to the highest level a spike would ever need, or you're coding something on your own to raise and lower the throughput via the Azure SDK (which becomes a nightmare when there is more than one source of spike against that collection).

The pricing model is ridiculous. Since the underlying architecture (most especially at the 250GB tier) seems meant to scale well anyway, we should simply be charged per-use.

Side note, for it to be dynamic, you *are* writing code, since there doesn't seem to be any rules-oriented solution under Azure to help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just have to code your own throttling as indicated by documentdb.  If you get a DocumentClientException where ex.StatusCode == 429 then do a await Task.Delay(ex.RetryAfter), then try again. until you get some other exception or it succeeds.